# Why do IPS/OLED need to be covered with glass when e-paper does not?

Tags: lcd, display, oled, e-ink

I wonder why the major criteria of comparison of [IPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPS_panel)/[OLED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED) displays is how reflective they are, but [e-paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper) seems just to "enjoy" direct incoming light without that side effect.

I've tried web search and as I understood it is glass-like (e.g. matte displays are not literal glass covered AFAIK) cover that gives reflections. The question is then why do IPS/OLED need to be protected by a glass-like cover, but e-paper does not?

I recall how LEDs in a lamp look - not reflective. I wonder how an OLED panel looks like without he glass cover. How would the absence of a cover affect its life span, could it be cleaned, etc.

ADDED:

I do not own a microscope and not very good in physics. Here is what I've done now: looked again at LEDS in a forehead lamp - they do not look reflective. Looked at the window glass - slightly reflective, added paper outside to the glass - very reflective, looked at just the paper - not reflective. So from all that I reason displays (at least OLEDs, though lamp featured not OLEDs) are reflective due to a coating on top of the LDs. Displays are not produced without coating because it would make the surface much more prone to damage and there is no commercially viable technology to fill-in gaps between LEDs (to produce a flat surface to enable easy cleaning) without adding coating on top of leds.

I want to try to use the trick from [Remove LCD/LED display anti-glare coating (from matte to glossy screen)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKTAbyt61h0) to try to remove outer coating from display (not working now anyway.)

Comment: Did you know there are multiple types of LCDs displays? The ones you are used on smartphones and computer monitors are transmissive. The ones on scientific calculators and digital watches are reflective. Transflective displays also exist which are a combination of the two and are much rarer bit work in sunlight and in the dark, but make compromises to do so. They have less vivid colours and contrast than transmissive but aren't as clear in sunlight as reflective. I have one but have yet to fire it up. Not sure how it looks like in person.

Comment: @DKNguyen, yep, ips / oled are transmissive AFAIK

Comment: Correct, but my understanding is that they don't necessarily *have* to be. Well, maybe OLED does.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I've recently read about transreflective Do they have negative effect of reflections on picture?

Comment: What do you mean? The difference between transmissive and reflective is that transmissive has its own backlight and reflective reflects ambient lighting for use as the backlight. You could make a reflective colour LCD, but no one does. Transflective is more readable in daylight than transmissive is, but not as much as reflective displays. So I guess the answer to your question is they shouldn't have as much glare that makes them unreadable in sunlight as transmissive displays. Maybe your question is really why do transmissive displays have such a shiny glass cover but not reflective displays?

Comment: @DKNguyen, I understood they use some of sunlight to brighten up the picture. But it does not negate the possibility of seeing your face in them theoretically. But how is it in practice? Do you know already? (you wrote you have not used your own yet, but I guess you could have seen some)

Comment: I haven't seen any functioning. They are super rare and could never get a market foothold. I should have bought two or three of the one I have when I found it especially since it was huge and actually had the correct driver board and inputs I wanted. It tooks years of searching. Good for FPV when you have glasses and can't wear goggles or just don't want to stick your head in video goggles.

Comment: Does that help? https://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/triple_a_plus/technology/03/index4.html

Comment: @DKNguyen, our discussion made me understrand that I do not recall reading how transmissive displays absorb incoming light... as of now I guess they just disperse it.

Comment: For decades reflective and transreflective LCDs were extremely common.  Gameboys, iPods, etc all used them.  They became a lot less popular as high efficiency LED backlighting became available, but they're still used occasionally. Additionally, matte LCDs definitely exist, and are great for things like laptops.

Comment: @DKNguyen OLED dispkay does not have a backlight .. the pixels themselves illuminate

Comment: @user1850479 Oh, the Gameboy (I assumed Colour?) was transflective? When were iPods transflective? I guess I never owned one but when I held them they certainly didn't seem like it.

Comment: @user1850479, matte displays are certainly reflective, less than glossy, still... I'm on matte now and see shape of my body on dark background. What coating does matte use?